# Sum of each row of 2d array. Inside a method

Tags: java, arrays, sum

```java
public class MagicSquare {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        int[][] tabela = {{ 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }};

        System.out.println(d1(tabela));
        System.out.println(d2(tabela));
    System.out.print(poVrsticah(tabela));


    }

    //diagnal1
    public static int d1(int[][] tab){
      int vsota=0;
      for (int i=0;i<tab.length ;i++ ) {
        for (int j=0;j<tab[i].length ;j++ ) {
          if (i==j) {
            vsota+=tab[i][j];
          }
        }
      }
        return vsota;
    }

    //diagnal2
    public static int d2(int[][] tab){
      int vsota=0;
      for (int i=0;i<tab.length ;i++ ) {
        for (int j=0;j<tab[i].length ;j++ ) {
          if (i+j==tab.length-1) {
            vsota+= tab[i][j];
          }
        }
      }
        return vsota;
    }

    //Method rows
    public static int[] poVrsticah(int[][]tab){
        int[] rez = new int[tab.length];
    for (int i=0;i<tab.length ;i++ ) {
            for (int j=0;j<tab[i].length ;j++ ) {
        rez[i]+= tab[i][j];
            }
        }
    return rez;
    }
    //method column
    public static int[] poStolpcih(int[][]tab){
    int[] rez = new int[tab.length];
        for (int i=0;i<tab.length ;i++ ) {
            for (int j=0;j<tab[i].length ;j++ ) {
                //Code here(1 line missing)
            }
        }
    return rez;
    }

}
```

My teacher sent me an email sending me back corrected code which I dont know how to fill out fully.The exercise is to sum up rows and columns in a 2d array. In the comments he left He said only 1 line was missing. I do not know what to  put in their place. I've tried putting in rez[i]+= tab[i][j]; to Sum it up. But it ends up writing out "[I@2c7b84de". Which I read is a problem with int and string conversions. I'm not sure this is the right approach as I'm lost in the sauce. Please help

Comment: for getting normal string instead of  "[I@2c7b84de", you need to override your method

Comment: I think it should be `rez[j]+= tab[i][j];`. Also, if provided input is not square matrix i.e. number of rows = columns, then you need to use `int[] rez = new int[tab[0].length];` for columns. And for solving `"[I@2c7b84de"`, you can just loop over output array and print its elements.

Answer (score 0):

This works for any matrix not only for square matrix which means it is no necessary to have same number of rows and columns in 2D array.

```
public static int[] calculateSumRow(int[][] array) {
        int length = array.length;

        int sum = 0, pos = -1;
        int[] toReturn = new int[array.length];

        for (int[] a : array) {
            pos++;
            int length2 = a.length;

            for (int x = 0; x < length2; x++)
            {
                sum += a[x];
            }

            toReturn[pos] = sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
```

Then to print the output use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(calculateSumRow(your_matrix)));`

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to update this question.

to fix the output use `rez[j]+= tab[i][j];` -thanks semicolon

And to fix "[I@2c7b84de" just call the method like   `poVrsticah(tabela);`

My final code ends up looking like https://justpaste.it/8gflr